# Git : What is my remote url?

Tags: git

[image]

I have a local git repo, and I'd like to git push to a new server where I have initialized a (non-bare) repo at 'gitrepo' (screenshot). Locally I have:

```
repo    ssh://deploy@198.xxx.xxx.xxx/gitrepo (fetch)
repo    ssh://deploy@198.xxx.xxx.xxx/gitrepo (push)
```

when I do:

```
$ git push repo myproject
....
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending command: git-receive-pack '/gitrepo'
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
fatal: '/gitrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2836, received 2588 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9421.9, received 8598.0
debug1: Exit status 128
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Am I pushing to the wrong url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for `/gitrepo` in the root directory. To make it look relative to the home directory of the target user of the ssh, use

```
ssh://deploy@198.xxx.xxx.xxx/~/gitrepo
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Am I pushing to the wrong url?*

Yes. Here's the important line in the ssh debug gobbledygook.

```
fatal: '/gitrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
```

You're logging in successfully with SSH, but your URL is wrong. I can't say what the right URL is. You could have the wrong path, you could have the wrong host. The path might need a .git on the end. You should ask someone on the project.