# Git : Where are the source files in my working directory?

Tags: git

[image]

Following the directions in [Git : What is my remote url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839422/git-what-is-my-remote-url/41839516#41839516) I have been able to git push a local git repo to a new server where I have initialized a (non-bare) repo at 'gitrepo' (screenshot).

My plan was link gitrepo to the server (its a django project), but I do not see any source files in the working directory. Why not and how can I get then in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing to a non-bare repository does *not* automatically update the working directory files. So, you will need to open a shell window, change to your directory called `gitrepo`, and run:

```
git reset --hard master
```

That will populate the working directory with all the files from the `master` branch (substitute branch name as needed). You will also have to do this every time you push.

Comment: Thank you. Could a checkout accomplish the same thing? http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#checkout

Comment: @user61629: A `checkout` usually works too, but will fail if for example any of the files in that working directory have been modified. The `reset --hard` command makes it work every time, even if files have been changed.